# Scanf takes two values in loop for standard input but needs to take only one to end loop

Tags: c, scanf

So one of the requirements for this code is that it takes the scan of the score and name from the same line so I have them in the same scanf and that entering q will break the loop and stop the input. The issue is that when entering Q without a number it will take another input before stopping the loop.
Are there any fixes I can do to make this work?

```
     while(entered_name[0] != 'Q' && entered_name[1] != 0)
     {
        
        scanf(" %s %d", entered_name, &new_score);
        if(entered_name[0] == 'q')
        {
            entered_name[0] = toupper(entered_name[0]);
        }
     }
```

Comment: If you insist on using `scanf` then you might want to look at its documentation. At its return value in particular.

Comment: You should probably not use one scanf to read both values.  And you should certainly check the value returned by scanf.

Comment: _Side note:_ Aside from suggestions about use of `scanf`, how about simplifying the loop: `while (1) { scanf(" %s %d", entered_name, &new_score); if ((toupper((unsigned char) entered_name[0]) == 'Q') && (entered_name[1] == 0)) break; }`

Comment: I suggest that you don't use `scanf`, but use `fgets` to read a whole line. You can then use `sscanf` on the memory buffer which contains the line contents. This has the advantage that the function will always return immediately and won't wait for additional data, even if it can't match both fields.

Comment: Good luck with your homework.  I assume this is homework?  I'm annoyed with your instructor for giving you this problem.  It's a terrible assignment, divorced from reality.  You'll learn a lot about the benighted `scanf` function while completing this exercise, it's true, but in the end, `scanf` is just about useless.  So learning how to do something sophisticated like this using `scanf` is like learning how to run a Formula 1 race on a two-wheeled tricycle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should *consume* the input line with `fgets()` because `scanf()` can get stuck as soon as the actual input does not match what is expected in the format string.

Then in a second time, you can analyse the obtained line with `sscanf()`.

The result gives the number of `%` that were successfully extracted (starting from the left), thus you can distinguish the cases where one or two information were given on this line.

```
/**
  gcc -std=c99 -o prog_c prog_c.c \
      -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion \
      -Wc++-compat -Wwrite-strings -Wold-style-definition -Wvla \
      -g -O0 -UNDEBUG -fsanitize=address,undefined
**/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int
main(void)
{
  char entered_name[100]="";
  int new_score=-1;
  while((strcmp(entered_name, "Q")!=0)&&
        (strcmp(entered_name, "q")!=0))
  {
    char line[100];
    if(fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin)==NULL)
    {
      break; // cannot read standard input any more
    }
    int r=sscanf(line, "%s %d", entered_name, &new_score);
    switch(r) // number of % extracted
    {
      case 1:
      {
        printf("entered name only: %s\n", entered_name);
        break;
      }
      case 2:
      {
        printf("entered name and score: %s %d\n", entered_name, new_score);
        break;
      }
      default:
      {
        printf("sorry, I didn't understand.\n");
      }
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to extract both the name and the score from the stream in a single call.  When you read `entered_name`, the score entry, if provided will remain buffered and will be read by the next call:

So for example:

```
    for(;;)
    {
        scanf(" %s", entered_name);
        if( tolower(entered_name[0]) == 'q' && entered_name[1] == '\0' )
        {
            break ;
        }
        scanf(" %d", &new_score);
        
        printf( "> %s : %d\n", entered_name, new_score ) ;
    }

    printf( "End\n" ) ;
```

In my test output:

```
hjsdhsj 34                                                                                                                                                                         
> hjsdhsj : 34                                                                                                                                                                       
jkdfslkdflksdfj 99                                                                                                                                                                 
> jkdfslkdflksdfj : 99                                                                                                                                                               
q                                                                                                                                                                                  
End
```

The wisdom and safety of using `scanf` in that manner is another manner.  Lack of error checking and overflow protection is certainly an issue..